# Scale Object By Percent in SmartDraw 2010

Tags: smartdraw

Does anybody know how to scale an object by percent (%) in SmartDraw?  When I right-click an object and select Position & Size from the context-menu, it gives me options to scale  by absolute values only.  This would be fine, except I have multiple differently sized objects that I want to re-scale (they've already each been roughly scaled by grouping and dragging the corner) to the same relative size.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to resize the objects by percentage when you are in SmartDraw.  Once you export your document, if you are using a program that allows for resizing by percentage you can do it there.